# System does not boot with DisplayPort plugged in

Tags: bios, troubleshooting, displayport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gigabyte GA-Z77X-D3H MB problems](https://superuser.com/questions/443063/gigabyte-ga-z77x-d3h-mb-problems)

Swapped in a new motherboard and CPU today, and...
My system would not boot with any DisplayPort monitor plugged in, but seems to work fine with DVI.

System is: Asus P8Z77-V LX motherboard, Asus 6870 DirectCU graphics card, i5 3570K processor.
The same graphics card was running triple monitor setup previously with AMD CPU and matching motherboard, but now has some kind of issue with the new motherboard.

Symptoms when powering on: short flash of power LED, fans barely move and it's silent. After 5-10 seconds it does the same again. If I disconnect DP cable during that time, it starts: fans spin up, DVI output gets signal, BIOS POSTs, OS loads.
Once the system is running, I can attach DP monitors, they get signal and I have functional 3-monitor setup. Once running, it can handle a reboot, but won't power on after a power off.

I've updated BIOS, and tried changing few things there (power surge protection, USB booting, primary display to PCIE) but symptoms so far stay the same. Also tried swapping places of the two external power cables for graphics card.

Disconnecting and reconnecting monitors on each power up is not that great. Any ideas what to try?